# jQuery ajax load not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

This example

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#test').load('doesntmatter');
});
</script>
```

seemed to me like it is identical to the examples for the [ajax load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). As the code snippet can tell you, it actually errors out with

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js is the slim edition of jquery, which does not include ajax. slim is the default version included in an Express server. Use the full version of jquery at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 4):

Here's a screenshot of the jquery downloads from the jquery [download page](https://jquery.com/download/) (https://jquery.com/download/)
It is easy NOT to notice this line.
Since many people are using jquery ajax, maybe they should rename the file as `jquery-slim-no-ajax.js`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you don't include jquery library **after your js** code!
Especially be careful if you use **bootstrap**!

I had the problem - I didn't see the part of bootstrap code in the *footer.php*, which had another jquery library - which caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this script link to post in your HTML that includes the ajax library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Try it. The load function works.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery format is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').load('doesntmatter');
    });
```

then add a page name in your directory or such into the load parameters

- Also make sure your script is the newest functional version

Comment: Remove .load and add `alert('test');`  does THAT work? If not your script files aren't loading for JS, but => isn't valid syntax so that's also an error.

Comment: Yes, using 'alert' instead works. => is [valid javascript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Regardless, changing it to your syntax gives the same error.

Comment: $ undefined only shows when your script src isn't importing or you messed up a function. Use this one `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That worked. It seems code.jquery.com is distributing a broken version of jquery. If you want to modify your answer to your last comment instead, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please  try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: "Your syntax is wrong" — No, it isn't. It's just using an ES6 arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **not use JQuery** for that :

This will ensure that JQuery is loaded before using it.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  $('#preloader').delay(400).fadeOut(500);
  // Do what you want, the window is entirely loaded and ready to use.
});
```

The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources finish loading.

Mozilla documentation: [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Edit : According to the question to not confusing *window.loaded* and *jquery.load*

First, change *jquery.slim* to *jquery* like previous response

Second, use native event handler for best practice *(in my opinion)* with modern browsers.

```
// To be sure $ is defined
// Window loaded event
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

  // Now $ or JQuery is completly available
  // Now using JQuery.load() should be defined
  $('#test').load('doesntmatter');

  // Do what you want, the window is entirely loaded and ready to use.
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ is an AJAX function in jQuery > 3. This question is not related to load event.

Comment: And my response still the same because I had the same issue last week (never before) and it's the only simple and native solution that is solving my problem. 2 browsers, same issue _function ($ what you want) is not a function_ and I have try all you can do. `ready` is when the document is ready not the window. In JQuery : `$( window ).on( "load"...` but what do you do if $ is not defined !? So one case $ is not defined, other case function is not defined. In any case I have test (header, footer...), for me the window have to check that jquery is properly loaded before use.

Comment: _Note: I have change slim, etc, etc and test all solutions during 2 hours before posting that (I like to know why)._ I know there is something wrong somewhere in my page, I think it's Analytics and new privacy rules or something like that. Maybe that's can help someone to not loosing time like have done.

Comment: @IBaff, I understand your response, your right it's not the same things :) Thank you to precise this :)

Answer (score 0):

here is good advice, I hade the same issue with jquery .load function and other functions not loading, so ensure you use the same jquery path in every page,(the same version) and it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax load not a function

use below URL
src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'