# Jquery load is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to submit a form without reloading the page, I have my code below and a screenshot of my error. Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
      var register = $("#register").val();
            $(".form-message").load("inc/register.php", {
                username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        cpassword: cpassword,
                submit: register
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/im6oz6

Thanks for the help,
Ethan!

Comment: can you show your jquery script link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between normal and slim package of jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax load not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003790/jquery-ajax-load-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following post function

```
$.post('url',{params},function(res, err){
 /*your code here*/

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery **slim** (screenshot) which does not include *any* AJAX functionality.([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery))

Use jQuery instead.