# jquery load is not a function inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a starter on jquery. and I encountered this problem today. really hope someone can help.

```
$('#lecture').on('click', function() {
    $("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");
});
```

> error : course_page.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a
>   function

however,

```
$("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");
```

this line works by itself.

I already spent couple hours on this by searching through stackoverflow. I tried couple approaches such as: checked my version is not "slim", tried .on("load") instead of .load()...

forgot to mention:

```
$('#lecture').on('click', function() {
    $("#screen").html("lecture_page.html");
});
```

if I use the .html() method instead of .load(), it will function correctly and display the text "lecture_page.html" at the correct position.

**solved.**
**The reason ends up to be the global sidebar that I am using do have a slim version included in it.**
**Thank you guys for the fast responses.** 
This is my first question on stackoverflow. The experience was very good!

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  //alert('course page js connected');
$(function() {
    $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
});

$('#lecture').on('click', function() {
    $("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");
});
//error : course_page.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

//$("#screen").load("lecture_page.html"); //this line works fine, however the above "load" cannot be recognized


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//below is everything I have tried 

    // $("#lecture").click(function(e){
    //     //e.preventDefault();
    //     console.log("clicked");
    //     $("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");
    // });

//$("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");

// $(document).on('click','#lecture',function(e){
//     //e.preventDefault();
//     console.log("clicked");
//     $("#screen").load("lecture_page.html");
// });
</script>
```

Comment: you tried wrap your code into $(document),ready(function() { }); ?

Comment: According to your comments, the exact same line of code, just outside of the event handler, works - it may not work within the event handler context.

Comment: Are you loading 2 versions of jQuery.js in page?

Comment: can you show us the html structure?

Comment: @daremachine yes, they are in different html <div>, is this what causing problem?

Comment: @daremachine I tried the $(document),ready(function() { }); approach. It doesn't help

Comment: @JackBashford what you said is the problem.

Comment: @charlietfl only one.

Comment: Then perhaps you are using `load()` elsewhere also and loading a slim version of jQuery from there? There really isn't a logical reason for your problem without `$.fn.load` getting wiped out somehow

Comment: 1) Open your page in your browser. 2) Press Ctrl+U (or right-click -> _View page source_). 3) Hit Ctrl+F. 4) Type _"jquery"_. I can almost guarantee you'll find at least two and one of them will probably be **slim**. As a final effort, use your browser's _Sources_ developer console to see what scripts are included

Comment: @charlietfl solved, you are right. the global sidebar I am using does has a slim version : )

Comment: @Phil Thank you, problem solved. the problem is the global sidebar I am using do have the slim version

Comment: @Ding33 - instead of adding the answer as an edit inside your question, you should instead *answer your own question* by posting an answer below, which is a perfectly acceptable thing to do here on SO.

Comment: @billynoah Or just vote to close as [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46003790/283366) of the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50083822/283366) duplicates

Comment: @billynoah Good to know. will do it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem. thanks for the fast responses and help, everyone.

The reason ends up to be the global "sidebar.html" that I am using does have a jquery slim version included in it. After deleting it, everything worked.

Comment: Ty, same issue, the jQuery slim version blocked me from using .load and was driving me nuts, I found it in a link.